# How should I create a new table as response after joined query using sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using python+fastapi+sqlalchemy+postgresql to construct a backend service. I have 2 mapper models namely mapping to 2 different tables in my database.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Text, Column
Base = declarative_base()
class A(Base):
    __tablename__='A'
    address = Column(Text)
    '''
    some other fields in A
    '''
class B(Base):
    __tablename__='B'
    address = Column(Text)
    '''
    some other fields in B
    '''
```

Now I have query results using

```py
(a,b) = db.query(A).join(B,A.address=B.address).first()
```

a and b are namely A object and B object
Now I wish I could construct a new table that does not exist in the database that contains all the fields in A and all the fields in B(contains only one address field), I have defined a new pydantic response model containing these fields, how can I achieve this?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
class C(BaseModel):
    '''
    All properties of A
    '''
    address: str
    '''
    All properties of B
    '''
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Comment: Do you want to actually create a _new database table_ with models, or only a Pydantic response that contains information from both model objects?

Comment: I want to create a Pydantic response that contains these information

Comment: `values = a.dict(), values.update(b.dict()), return C(**values)` should work? You might also be able to define C as inheriting from (A, B) as Python supports multiple inheritance.

Comment: I have figure out another way to solve this but your method is inspiring. Thanks!!